# PHP openssl_decrypt random_pseudo_bytes error, help me

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-openssl

I succeeded in encrypting the plaintext using PHP openssl, but with openssl_decrypt, I get this error.

```
�RC(�ɸ�gQ���삭
```

What is the reason for alien language to float? I think this is the problem:

```
openssl_random_pseudo_bytes (16).
```

`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(opensl_cipher_iv_length ("AES-128-CBC"));` is the same situation.

```
function aes_encode($text, $s_key){
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($text, "AES-128-CBC", $s_key, 0, $iv));
  }

  $encrypt_text = aes_encode($plaintext, $s_key);
  echo $encrypt_text;

function aes_decode($encrypt_text, $s_key){
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypt_text), "AES-128-CBC", $s_key, 0, $iv);
}

$decrypt_text = aes_decode($encrypt_text, $s_key);
echo $decrypt_text;

<result>
QUxwTUxiSTkwWFc2WE0zcmtSOXNHR0cyKzU1RWIvNkxnaGJTZmdnVlB4VT0=
�RC(�ɸ�gQ���삭
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same IV you encrypted with when decrypting:

```
function aes_encode($text, $s_key, $iv){
    return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($text, "AES-128-CBC", $s_key, 0, $iv));
}

function aes_decode($encrypt_text, $s_key, $iv){
    return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypt_text), "AES-128-CBC", $s_key, 0, $iv);
}
$plaintext = 'testtest';
$s_key = 'secret';
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

$encrypt_text = aes_encode($plaintext, $s_key, $iv);
echo $encrypt_text;

echo "\n";

$decrypt_text = aes_decode($encrypt_text, $s_key, $iv);
echo $decrypt_text;
```

Output

```
SVg2Y0FtV1h6RFZac2t5UjhxNDhpdz09
testtest
```

Comment: Note that IVs are not considered to be secret, and should change for each message that you encrypt. Many crypto libraries simply attach the IV to the ciphertext for transmission/storage, eg: simply prepending the IV to the ciphertext.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So I want to encrypt the plaintext in one PHP file and decode it in the other, how should I use random iv?